# Embedding a vertical reference line in chart

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, office365, microsoft-office-2019

I am using a combo chart and I have managed to reach as shown below

[image]

Below is the output that I am seeking. I am trying to add a vertical line for a specific date (say 11th Jul)

[image]

I googled a lot but unable to find a solution. I came across something which is closer to what I need. [Embedding a vertical reference line in Excel](https://www.storytellingwithdata.com/blog/2018/8/7/tactical-tip-embedding-a-vertical-reference-line-in-excel) but I am unable to achieve this as there is already a secondary axis. What is the best way to handle this?

Comment: At face value, without actually trying this, could you not adapt that linked solution but instead of 0 and 1, use formulas to find the MAX and MIN values of the calls or the conversion rate so this can be plotted on the existing axis?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @AdamV. The moment I reach step 6, the line disappears :( I also manually tried to put 0/100 as min/max values

Comment: Why are you trying to add a vertical line? What does it signify? I ask because perhaps there is a alternate solution that can have the same meaning.

Comment: My boss wants it. That date is a cutoff date. He wants to show it that way :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a bit of a workaround, not ideal, but could do the job. Let me know if it works for you

1. Insert a 3rd column for the cutoff in your table with a value equivalent to the the max value of your axis (in this case, `7000`)

[image]

2. Insert a combo chart with the third series as columns

[image]

3. Select the bar and adjust width and colour by Formatting the Data Series
4. Format the left Axis so the range is between `0` and `7000`

[image]

Comment: Loved it. Thanks a ton! I wish instead of column, I could show it as a dotted line... (If I am not asking for too much) I decreased the gap width to 500% but could not go beyond that...

Comment: Filling the column with an image or texture may do the trick

Comment: Thanks I had already thought of that and the results were not satisfactory :D If the width could have reduced then yes, that would have helped.

Comment: Instead of a column, make the added series a line chart series. There is only one non-zero point. Format it to have no marker, but add a drop line, and format the drop line as a dotted line. Or add error bars, no cap, value minus only, value 100%. Format as dotted line.